# Using BETWEEN to create exclusive set of intervals

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, intervals, between

I have a database that has id and distance columns. I need to count the number of ids that are between a certain distance.

For example, I want to count how many ids are between 1km and 2km in distance, so I'm using this code:

```
SELECT COUNT (distance)
FROM table
WHERE distance BETWEEN 1000 AND 2000
-- Returns a COUNT of 240,600
```

When I want to count the number of ids that are between 2km and 3km and I use the same query, but the "2km" value is counted in both queries as the BETWEEN operator is inclusive.

```
SELECT COUNT (distance)
FROM table
WHERE distance BETWEEN 2000 AND 3000
-- Returns a COUNT of 353,440
```

As I understand it the two queries above will both include rows where the distance is exactly 2000.

I'm curious to know if there is another way to count things like distance (and there are a lot of rows) or do I need to GROUP BY And then count?

Comment: To understand your question: you would like to know whether there is a way to count a number of rows in each distance interval?

Comment: Hi, yes, basically I need to know how many rows (id) have a distance between certain ranges. From 1km - 2km and 2km - 3km but using between, would count all the ids that are inclusive of 2km?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to SQL specs, this expression:

```
WHERE distance BETWEEN 1000 AND 2000
```

is same as:

```
WHERE distance >= 1000 AND distance <= 2000
```

From what I understand, you need to remove `=` from one of the endpoints to create mutually exclusive ranges. Depending on your definition of *between 1km and 2km* one of these set of conditions should be used:

```
WHERE distance >= 0    AND distance < 1000
WHERE distance >= 1000 AND distance < 2000
WHERE distance >= 2000 AND distance < 3000
```

Or

```
WHERE                     distance <= 1000
WHERE distance > 1000 AND distance <= 2000
WHERE distance > 2000 AND distance <= 3000
```

Comment: Thank you for this  - I did try this query but I'm also getting an error: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "<"
LINE 3: WHERE distance >= 2000 AND < 3000

Comment: It should be distance >= 2000 AND distance < 3000.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this sort of thing to get a histogram table

```sql
SELECT DIV(distance, 1000) * 1000 distance_from,
       (DIV(distance, 1000) * 1000) + 999 distance_to,
       COUNT(*) num
  FROM mytable
GROUP BY DIV(distance, 1000) * 1000
```

The expression `DIV(distance, 1000)` creates groups of distance values when you use it with `GROUP BY`.

As you have discovered, `BETWEEN` has limited usefulness for handling ranges of numbers.  You may want `distance >= 1000 AND distance < 2000` for the range [1000, 2000).

Comment: Thank you for your reply - I get an error - ERROR:  function div(double precision, integer) does not exist
When I use this code?

Comment: Try `1000.0` instead of `1000`. And, please edit your question to show us the output from `SHOW CREATE TABLE whateverYourTableName`

Comment: I tried to use 1000.0 
`SELECT DIV(distance, 1000.0) * 1000.0 distance_from,
       (DIV(distance, 1000.0) * 1000.0) + 999 distance_to,
       COUNT(*) num
  FROM route_api.route
GROUP BY DIV(distance, 1000.0) * 1000.0
LIMIT 10`
But still get an error. ERROR:  function div(double precision, numeric) does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT DIV(distance, 1000.0) * 1000.0 distance_from,
               ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
SQL state: 42883
Character: 8